# Unable to upload 100 MB file Using Rest Service in PCF

Tags: spring-boot, multipart, cloud-foundry

I have a requirement that requires to upload file up to 150MB. I have written a java based rest service using  Spring boot 1.5. I am not able to upload larger file. The code works for smaller file size. I have configured all payload/ multipart related configuration for tomcat.It is not working for large files. I am getting "502: Bad Gateway:Registered endpoint unable to handle the request. The code is deployed in Pivotal Cloud Foundry. My question is "Is there any size limit for payload that is configured at Go Router Level which is causing this issue?" Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would suggest:

1. Run your app locally. Ensure that you can upload a 150M+ file. That will ensure that you have Spring Boot configured correctly, and that there are no limits in Tomcat (embedded) or Spring which would cause this.
2. When you deploy to a Cloud Foundry installation, there will not be any additional size based restrictions. Gorouter does not directly limit the size of a file that can be uploaded. *However*, Gorouter has an upper limit on how much time a request can consume in it's entirety (i.e. receive request, process and respond). By default, that is 900s (your CF platform may differ, consult with your platform operator to get a specific value).

   I mention this because the upload bandwidth of your client will come into play here. If you have a client that is slowly uploading a 150M file, let's say it would take an hour to upload that file, then it will fail with a response like you're seeing.

   My suggestion to confirm, would be to run `cf logs` and look for the log entry tagged with `[RTR]` that corresponds to your failed request. It'll have the 502 status code. Now, check the response_time field and see if it matches the max request time as set on your platform (900s default). If it's a match, then that's your issue.

If none of that helps, you're going to need to look for more information. Perhaps try increasing the log levels and running `cf logs` to see if you get any more clues from your application.

Comment: Yes you are right. My client was slow in uploading the file. I am able to make it work. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase multipart size with configuraiton

`spring.http.multipart.max-file-size`=200MB // you ca

and

Tomcat's configuration or AP

```
webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml
<multipart-config>
   <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: I have added this configuration. It is still not working.